# How do I pass in a matrix of floats as a 2D texture to the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl

I have a matrix of nr x nc float values stored in

```
std::vector<float> data;
```

How do I pass in this matrix as a 2D texture to the fragment shader?

Which internalformat and format should I use as argument to glTexImage2D()?

Do I need to set

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

?

BTW: I do not understand the difference between GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT and GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT.
My data is tightly packed (alignment = 1). One command should be enough to tell OpenGL about this.

Comment: Did you try `GL_R32F` and `GL_FLOAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic matrix with arbitrary floats, and where you need 32 bit precision, I'd suggest using a single-channel 32 bit float format, as internal format. YOu have not specified which OpenGL version you target, so I assume "reasonably modern", so the internl format should be set to `GL_R32F`. As format, you want to use `GL_FLOAT` obviously, as that parameter describes the format your client data is in.

You can set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to any valid value <=4 (which is also the default) in this case, since a float is always 4 bytes, so each row of floats will always be a multiple of 4.

`GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is totally unrelated. It defines the alignment for *reading back* ("packing") of pixel data.

Comment: Thank you derhass! Using the GL_R32F the values come into the shader as the red component? Is this the same as GL_RED? Do I have to scale the values to be in the range [0,1] before sending them to the shader?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, they will be in the red channel. No, you do not need to scale them, you can use the full float range.